# TextRenderer.MeasureText returns same height for different widths

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing

I am trying to print an invoice using PrintDocument, the ProductName column height should differ for each row depending on the value/text of the productName. The width of productname column is fixed.

I need to calculate the height required for the productname to determine how many rows would accommodate on one page

To do so i used the following method

```
 Dim f As Font = Me.Font
 Dim SizeOfString As SizeF
 Dim DrawFormat As New TextFormatFlags
 
 DrawFormat = TextFormatFlags.Default Or TextFormatFlags.WordBreak
 
 SizeOfString = TextRenderer.MeasureText(ProductName, f, New Size(ProdNameSize.Width, Integer.MaxValue), DrawFormat)
```

I have two formats of invoice..
In one invoice format the width of the productname is 206 and in the other format its 180

But TextRenderer.MeasureText returns the same height for the Rectangle for both the widths

kindly advice..

Comment: Why would you expect the *height* of the rectangle to be different for items with different *width*?

Comment: `Dim DrawFormat = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak Or TextFormatFlags.NoPadding Or TextFormatFlags.NoClipping`. If both strings have the same Height, it means that the rendering of the text, with the specified Font and size constraint, requires the same number of lines for both strings. -- What is the value of `Font.Height` and `ProdNameSize.Width`? What does `ProdNameSize.Width` represent? Is it the width of a container or something else?

Comment: @Craig Because in a multiline text(without linebreaks), as the width changes, the no of lines required to draw the string would change.

Comment: @Jimi ProdNameSize.Width represents the width of the container

Comment: `code` e.Graphics.DrawString(ProductName, RegularFont, Brushes.Black, DrawRect, DrawFormat)`code` , The DrawRect is type of  'Rectangle' its width is predefined and its height needs to be calculated for each product.   Which is where i am facing the problem, i am getting same height for different widths of the DrawRect

Comment: What does *In one invoice format the width of the productname is 206 and in the other format its 180* mean? What is a *format*? What is *width*? Do you mean the width, in pixels, after the calculation or the number of chars in the string? What is `Me` in `Me.Font`? Is this a WinForms app? Other (tag the question accordingly)? is `Me` a Form? Other? -- If you want some help, you need to post (in the question's body, not in comments), these details (the strings to measure, all the values defined explicitly). I.e., nobody knows what `ProdNameSize.Width` is, whether it can change etc.